# How come DataContext property value get inherited by childs but not others?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am learning wpf and I have a dummy question.

When we set `DataContext` property of a parent, it gets inherited by its childs which can use the same binding but how come other properties not get inherited?

Yes it make sense that if we set the parent's name (which is a property) to xyz, the child's name doesn't get set to the same which also has the same property but how is it that rule is different for DataContext property?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Are you trying to find out why the mechanism that allows `DataContext` to be inherited does not automatically cause all other properties to be inherited? Or are you asking why the _design_ of WPF is such that other properties aren't inherited. Either way, **what makes you think there's any reason it should be different than it is?** What is the point of this question?

Comment: @PeterDuniho MI think my question is pretty clear. `DataContext` and others are all properties so why is the behavior for one property is the question.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Do let me know which line is confusing in the question and I will fix it.

Comment: The whole thing is confusing. Please see my previous comment above to see exactly what you would need to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of the DataContext property is inherited because this is explicitly requested by setting `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits` on registration of the property.

From the [Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/FrameworkElement.cs,d2d98a3022fbac2f):

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DataContextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "DataContext",
        typeof(object),
        _typeofThis,
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits,
            new PropertyChangedCallback(OnDataContextChanged)));
```

See also the *Dependency Property Information* in the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext?view=netframework-4.8#remarks):

**Dependency Property Information**

```
Identifier field                   DataContextProperty
Metadata properties set to true    Inherits
```

Comment: So this essentially is different from other properties in this respect. Curious if there are any other properties as well that gets inherited? Thanks.

Comment: There are a few, like Foreground, FontSize and other Font related properties of the TextBlock class.